# Seeking jQuery editor widget that supports URL/Link resolution automagically like Facebook

Tags: jquery, facebook, url, widget, rich-text-editor

My site is an entertainment-based social-media site that relies on user generated content.  Currently, when users create content, I only support **raw text**.

What I'm looking for is a **jQuery widget or control** that feels like the **text editor in Facebook**. I need something that can resolve a URL or Link and magically turn it into a clickable link.  But it can't rely on technologies like **BBCode** or other tag-based implementations, at least in terms of what's exposed to end users.  At one point, we did have a BBCode-based editor, but we yanked it after it tested poorly with anyone but technology geeks.

The Holy Grail of editors would include the following features:

- **URL / Link resolution**, with the ability to optionally call a 3rd party service like bit.ly (via a web method or something)
- Image resolution: user pastes in a URL to an image, and the editor recognizes this and creates an `<IMG>` tag with all the goodness in place
- Video resolution: same deal for videos as with Images.

What I don't need (currently) is any support for formatting: bold, italics, quoting, indenting, bulleting, etc.  All of these features are much less important than being able to resolve a URL pasted in to the editor.

I'll probably end up having to implement this myself, and I don't mind this as I enjoy writing jQuery widgets. In this case, if you have any anecdotes or tips to offer up that may be helpful, I'd appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering this myself because I don't think there is such an editor outside of Facebook, or at least one that feels like Facebook's but doesn't require the resources of a multi-billion dollar company to pull off.

In the end, we used a combination of jQuery and a server-side PageMethod in C# to do both URL shortening and sanitizing (using the Microsoft AntiXSS library). Any user-supplied text is run through this PageMethod, and the resulting sanitized HTML fragment is returned to the client.

So, you don't get the instant gratification that Facebook's editor provides, but at least you can embed links in descriptions and comments. "Something is often better than nothing."